# htaccess mod rewrite url with adding up & parameter in url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

We have a specific section of games called com_games. Could someone advise on how to rewrite url by adding parameter of & through htaccess so as have 301 redirect

From

```
 http://www.abc.com/?page=4&option=com_games&view=list&Itemid=2
```

to

```
 http://www.abc.com/?page=4&&option=com_games&view=list&Itemid=2
```

This needs to be achieve in all pagination pages, How to append & in the url for 301 redirection

Comment: You need to add `&` directly after `page` parameter?

Comment: actually, the site pages are crawled in duplicate with single & and double &&. What's the correct way through htaccess to redirect all pages with single & to 301 redirect to && pages

Comment: Okay, but you haven't answered to my question.

Comment: Yes, need to add & after the page parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/\?(page=[^&]+)&([^&][^\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1&&%2 [R=301,L]
```